# I got problems here in creating a trigger for removing the line where count>10

Tags: sql, database, triggers

I need to create a trigger Graduation which automatically deletes students when their semesterCount would be greater than 10. The trigger should be after update. I do not know how to complete the whole trigger part. Have a look, pls.

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    major CHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    semesterCOUNT INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (101, 'CS', 6);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (102, 'C&M', 10);
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (103, 'CS', 9);

CREATE TRIGGER Graduation
AFTER UPDATE
ON Student
FOR EACH ROW
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Graduation
       ON student
       AFTER update
 AS
 DECLARE @crs_count int 
  SELECT @crs_count = COUNT(semesterCOUNT)
        from Student
if( @crs_count > 10 )
     you can use delete command here
```

This should give you idea to delete.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it gives syntax error

Comment: Can you share in more detail ? so that I can resolve it?